# How to check that if current user (ID) has posts or not wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Custom template. In it i want to check that if the current logged in user has custom posts named (student_form) or not if posts equals true i want to redirect it to some page other wise i want to show him/her a form which i created using wp fronted user.

Following code i wrote but its not redirecting to the desired Page if user has custom posts .

```
     <?php 
     /*
     * Template Name: Form Page
     */
     get_header(); 

     global $post,$current_user;
     get_currentuserinfo();

     if ($post->post_author == $current_user->ID) {
     exit( wp_redirect(http://MYurl/dashboard/') );

     }
     else
     {
     echo do_shortcode('[wpuf_form id="414"]');
     }

     wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
     get_footer(); 
     ?>
```

Comment: you are closing with endwhile, but where the loop starts?

Comment: Is the Wordpress Debug mode enabled to show any possible errors?

Comment: No how can i enable it?

Comment: Thats really not hard to find, 1sec Google....
https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: @RobinVinzenz i have edited my post please have a look

Comment: @VidyaNair i have edited my post please have a look